# Обновление картинки js без мерцаний каждые 0,1 cекунды

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю проект и надо обновлять картинку(передаётся с клиента в формате base64) без обновления страницы. На данный момент есть такой (говно)код, но при обновлении картинки происходит мерцание(видно как она загружается... рай для эпилептика). Как сделать всё это добро без мерцаний?
P.S. В качестве бэкенда используется python(nginx+flask).
P.P.S Да, сейчас стоит 1 секунда, но хотелось бы дойти до 0,1.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const method_name = 'getframe';
        const url='http://stream.std-567.ist.mospolytech.ru/';  
        function update(){
            Http.onerror =  function(){     
                //alert("something went wrong"); 
            }
            Http.open('POST', url + method_name);   
            Http.send();

            function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
                    var binary_string =  window.atob(base64);
                    var len = binary_string.length;
                    var bytes = new Uint8Array( len );
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    return bytes.buffer;
                }



            Http.onload = function(){           
                Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>
                {
                    //console.log();
                    screenpanel.src ="data:image/png;base64," + Http.responseText;
                }       
            }
        }
        setInterval(update,1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: а что вы делает цель какая может по другому можно я зашел и не понятно что вообще хотите сделать

Comment: у вас вся консолль в ошибка в секунду более 100 ошибок

Comment: Почему не используете Fetch API? Намного удобнее

Comment: screenpanel это что img  если до то src не верный будет думаю из за этого ошибки

Comment: В целом стриминговое приложение. Получаем скриншот экрана в base64 из клиента и на сервере эту картинку отображаем. Этим скриптом дёргаем, чтобы картинка обновлялась только(с промежутком в секунду сейчас) , а не вся страница.

Comment: На данный момент когда идёт поток от клиента  - сервер все показывает, но при обновлении картинки мерцания из-за обновления.

Comment: Fetch API что-то слишком медленно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать 2 картинки. План примерно такой:

1. Расположить два `<img>` элемента один поверх другого с разным `z-index`;
2. После того как получена base64-картинка, записать её в нижний `<img>`-элемент;
3. Поменять картинки местами за счёт `z-index`. (Возможно тут понадобиться небольшая задержка c помощью `setTimeout`)
4. Загрузить следующую base64-картинку. После чего вернуться к пункту 2.

P.S. Но я бы всё же советовал бы вам копать в сторону `canvas` или `video`.